# android calendar view date picker

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-datepicker

I want to set a `DatePicker` for user to choose a date, after user presses the `EditText` and chooses the date. I want it returned to EditText field. How may I do that?

Here is my code :

```
public class CompletedWorksActivity extends ActionBar {
    private TextView text_date;
    private DatePicker date_picker;
    private Button button;
    private EditText from;
    private EditText to;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 100;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle menuinstance){
        super.onCreate(menuinstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.completed_works);

        Intent intent = getIntent(); //gaunam
        User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("user");
        from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datefrom);
        to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateto);
    }


}
```

And xml needed for this code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchFields"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:paddingRight="13dp"
    android:paddingTop="22dp" >

    <!-- Object ID field -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/datefrom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_datefrom_field"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:minHeight="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#404041" />

    <!-- Key field -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_dateto_field"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:minHeight="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#404041" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is it better to start other activity for choosing a date with picker, or call date picker in this activity somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I misread your description, but I'll post this anyway.

I took your description to mean that you wanted a `DatePickerDialog` to open upon clicking on the `from` and `to` `EditText`s. The following code will open the Dialog when either gets focus, then set the corresponding `EditText`'s text to the date upon closing.

```
public class CompletedWorksActivity extends Activity
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{ 
    private TextView text_date;
    private Button button; 
    private EditText from; 
    private EditText to;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    private DatePickerDialog date_picker;
    private boolean fromEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle menuinstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(menuinstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = getIntent(); //gaunam
        User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("user");

        from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datefrom);
        to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateto);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        date_picker = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));        

        from.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);

        to.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker dp, int y, int m, int d)
    {
        String cheapDate = (m + 1) + "/" + d + "/" + y;

        if (fromEdit)
        {
            from.setText(cheapDate);
        }
        else
        {
            to.setText(cheapDate);
        }
    }

    private View.OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {           
            if (hasFocus)
            {
                //   \/ Optional \/
                EditText edit = (EditText) v;
                int len = edit.getText().toString().length();

                if (len == 0)
                {
                //   /\ Optional /\

                    fromEdit = v.getId() == R.id.datefrom;
                    date_picker.show();

                //   \/ Optional \/                 
                }
                else
                {
                    edit.setSelection(0, len);
                }
                //   /\ Optional /\
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Edit:**

I cleaned up the code a bit, and added additional functionality, if you care to use it. Now, when an `EditText` gets the focus, if it is empty, it will open the Dialog. If it is not empty, the Dialog will *not* show, but instead the  `EditText`'s text will be selected.

If you just want the Dialog to open, empty or not, just omit the code between the marked "Optional" comments.

Also, as of API Level 11 (HONEYCOMB), you can do the following:

```
date_picker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
```

Comment: your solution is awesome. but is it possible to call not scroll able date picker ? is it possible to call calendar view date picker ?

Comment: date_picker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
after adding this line i get both pickers

Comment: its all ok, i found that if i write 'date_picker.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false)'
it disper.

Comment: what if i need to use that date i chosen ? how may i manage it ?

Comment: i would like just to get a date-  y, m and d separately, that i could send it to my server, to read it simply.

Answer (score 1):

call date picker in this activity only, that is how i prefer. it is some thing like this

```
  private void callDatePic() {
    new DatePickerDialog(AddFriendActivity.this, d, c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            c.get(Calendar.MONTH),       c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        date =  dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;          
        c1.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    dateFrom.setText(date);
    }

};
where c1 is Calender class object.
```

after this you will back to edit text where the edittext was filled with selected date.
you can follow the same step for other edit text field also
hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this component:
https://github.com/truefedex/android-date-picker

Like this:

```
if (calendarPopup == null) {
  calendarPopup = new PopupWindow(getContext());
  CalendarPickerView calendarView = new CalendarPickerView(getContext());
  CalendarNumbersView calendar = (CalendarNumbersView) calendarView.findViewById(com.phlox.datepick.R.id.calendar);
  calendar.setShowDayNames(false);
  calendarView.setListener(onDateSelectionListener);
  calendarPopup.setContentView(calendarView);
  calendarPopup.setWindowLayoutMode(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(llCalendar.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  calendarPopup.setHeight(1);
  calendarPopup.setWidth(llCalendar.getWidth());
  calendarPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
}
calendarPopup.showAsDropDown(llCalendar);
```

Comment: CalendarPickerView component is very cool - thanks for sharing the project.  I am starting to use it now, has been very easy to work with so far.  Is there a way to set a cut-off date  ? In my case I am looking to make *today, the current day when picker is being used* the last date available for selection.  I guess there could also be a use case for the opposite .. for *"max earliest date"*.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethod;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 EditText from,to;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
      //  User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("user");
        from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datefrom);
        to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateto);
        from.setOnClickListener(this);
        to.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    // To Hide KeyBoard 
    InputMethodManager i = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    i.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((EditText)v).getWindowToken(), 0);


    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final String seperator = " / "; 
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day =  c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    OnDateSetListener listener = new OnDateSetListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // YYYY/MM/DD
            //change the format as per your requirement
            ((EditText)v).setText(year + seperator + monthOfYear + seperator + dayOfMonth);

        }
    };

    DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(this,listener,year , month, day);
    d.show();

}


 }
```

This Code will set On Click Listener  when ever user click on any of the edit text.
DatePickerDialog box will open to select a date